# Challenge of accessing folder from Netbean on macOS (Version 10.15)

Tags: macos-catalina

I have recently install Netbean V.8.2 on macOS V.10.15 the challenge am facing is I can't access image folders and mysql java connector from netbean enviroment. Can anybody help

Thanks